# Close views bootstrap accordion block when next block is open

Tags: jquery, drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a page in Drupal 7 that contain four blocks using Bootstrap accordion format.  By default the first block is open.  I added the functionality using this jquery

```
$("#collapse-1-0").addClass("in");
```

Each view block has a different id and when I click on the next view block I would like to be able to close the already open view block.  Below is the code that is currently being used on the site.

```
<section id="block-views-tr-plus-at-a-glance-block-1" class="block block-views contextual-links-region clearfix">

<div id="views-bootstrap-accordion-1" class="views-bootstrap-accordion-plugin-style panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#views-bootstrap-accordion-1" href="#collapse-1-0" aria-expanded="false">
            TRUE REISHI PLUS AT A GLANCE          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse-1-0" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">

  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <div class="field-content"><ul><li>Made entirely from concentrated Reishi spore oil, making it the most potent Reishi supplement available.</li>
<li>Each serving contains over 120 mg of triterpenes, the most active and therapeutic constituent of Reishi.</li>
<li>Harvested in small batches and cultivated for maximum potency using meticulous cultivation methods perfected through decades of research and experience.</li>
<li>Developed from our premium strain of red Reishi, grown in natural woodlands in the</li>
<li>Chinese countryside.</li>
<li>All natural with no preservatives or additives.</li>
<li>100% vegan.</li>
<li>Packaged with fully recyclable materials.</li>
<li>Produced under Certified Good Manufacturing Practices (GMP) and subject to high levels of quality control</li>
</ul></div>  </div>        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The second block code is as follows

```
<section id="block-views-tr-plus-at-a-glance-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region clearfix">
<div id="views-bootstrap-accordion-2" class="views-bootstrap-accordion-plugin-style panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#views-bootstrap-accordion-2" href="#collapse-2-0" aria-expanded="true">
            PRODUCT INFORMATION          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse-2-0" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <div class="panel-body">

  <div class="views-field views-field-body">        <div class="field-content"><p>With True Reishi Plus, we’ve created a more powerful Reishi supplement, optimized to support your immune system, protect against aging, strengthen your cardiovascular system, and stimulate your overall health and well&shy;being. Packed with a concentration of Reishi’s active ingredients, the powerful triterpenes known for healing the body, True Reishi Plus is effective for maximum healing and support. Taken with True Reishi, True Reishi Plus enhances the active Reishi ingredients present in True Reishi, encouraging maximum healing and increasing the overall nutrition and effectiveness of our Reishi supplements.</p>
<p>Using advanced technology, we extract the spore oil from our Reishi mushrooms, producing a<br>100% natural spore oil supplement which is both rare and potent. Historically, Reishi’s spore oil––the most precious and powerful Reishi constituent––was locked inside of the Reishi mushroom, unable to be utilized for its healing properties. Our supercritical extraction method naturally draws out the active constituents contained within the Reishi spores, delivering the<br>most prized and rare aspect of Reishi to you. This highly concentrated and precious oil results in a premium supplement with maximal impact.</p>
<p>Add True Reishi Plus to your True Reishi Regimen to complement and continue the natural healing power of True Reishi. Taken together, True Reishi and True Reishi Plus deliver a powerful blend of triterpenes and polysaccharides, leading to overall body support and radiant health.</p>
</div>  </div>        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So block-1 is open by default and I would like it to close when the second block (called block) is clicked on

Answer (score 0):

You can find every id that starts with "collapse-", remove the class "in", and then add the class "in" to the field that has been clicked.

(untested) Example:

```
$("div[id^='collapse-']).click(function(){
    $("div[id^='collapse-']).removeClass('in');
    $(this).addClass('in');
}
```